# Failed to load decrypted class from custom classloader spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, encryption, classloader

I am creating a spring-boot application which is trying to encrypt the class files on compile and decrypt them during start-up. I have encrypted the files and added in to the JAR. To achieve the decryption portion, I have written a custom classloader which is called in Main method. I need to load the decrypted classes to the classloader.

I have tried 2 approaches.

Approach1:
in Main method --> Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoade(new MyClassLoader());

MyClassLoader.java extends ClassLaoder, and has overridden loadClass(name). When a class is loaded, I check if it contains my package, and decrypt it and call the defineClass(). Finally calls the super.loadClass(name).

Issue in this is, some spring classes will be called before my local classes are decrypted, hence throws an error.

Approach2:
Create an instance of MyClassLoader() and calls a custom method that will decrypt the class, call defineClass(). Finally, I also tried adding resolveClass(). But, findClass throws ClassNotFound exception.

How can I add the decrypted class into the classloader before any of the classes are loaded?